# Invalid index n for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=n

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

NHibernate throws an Exception: "Invalid index n for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=n." when I attempt to save a Meter object. The problem is with the CurrentReading property. If I comment that mapping out, all is well. Also if I manually set the CurrentReading in the database NHibernate queries it fine.

I'm relatively new to NHibernate, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Meter
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual MeterReading CurrentReading { get; protected set; }

    private IList<MeterReading> _readings;
    public virtual ReadOnlyCollection<MeterReading> Readings
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<MeterReading>(_readings); }
    }

    public virtual void AddMeterReading(MeterReading MeterReading)
    {
        _readings.Add(MeterReading);
        if (CurrentReading == null || MeterReading.ReadingTimestamp > CurrentReading.ReadingTimestamp)
        {
            CurrentReading = MeterReading;
        }
    }
}

public class MeterReading
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Usage { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ReadingTimestamp { get; set; }
}
```

And this fluent nhibernate mapping file:

```
public sealed class MeterMap : ClassMap<Meter>
{
    public MeterMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        References(m => m.CurrentReading)
            .Column("CurrentMeterReadingId")
            .LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.None()
            .Nullable();

        HasMany(x => x.Readings)
            .KeyColumn("MeterId")
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .LazyLoad()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public sealed class MeterReadingMap : ClassMap<MeterReading>
{
    public MeterReadingMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.ReadingTimestamp)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Usage)
            .Precision(18)
            .Scale(8)
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that it has something to do with mapping the same column twice.  This is what this error generally means.  You might try this alternative mapping since you aren't using cascading on CurrentMeterReading:

```
References(m => m.CurrentReading)
        .Column("CurrentMeterReadingId")
        .Not.Update()
        .Not.Insert();
        .Nullable();
```

Also I believe lazy loading is enabled by default so I don't think there is a need to specify that in the mapping.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My mistake was; I had an association property(many-to-one) and in my mapping didn't specify `insert="false"` for that association.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe far too late (question posted in 2012), but could be useful to others, I've had a similar issue. I'm not using Fluent mapping, but I'm using hbm files.
From what I see, you have a Meter which has a List of Readings. You have marked this List property as Inverse, which is good.
But my understanding, at least with hbm mapping files, is that you have to add a "parent" property on the child item (Reading in your example) to point back to the parent (Meter in your example).

This is my parent object (called Constraint):

```
    <list name="Values" access="field.camelcase-underscore" table="[ConstraintValue]" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
        <key column="ConstraintId" not-null="true"/>
        <list-index column="OrderId" />
        <one-to-many class="ConstraintValue" />
    </list>
```

And this is my child object (called Constraint Value):

```
    <!--Parent-->
    <many-to-one name="Constraint" access="field.camelcase-underscore" class="Constraint" column="ConstraintId" cascade="merge" not-null="true"/>
```

And it's also important to remember that in the code, you can't just add a child to the parent:

```
Meter.Readings.Add(newReading);
```

you also have to set the parent property of the child:

```
newReading.Meter = theParentMeter;
```

In my own example, I've got an Add method in the parent class to do it for me (set the collection property as read-only to force users of the code to call this Add method, ensuring the parent is always set):

```
public virtual void AddConstraintValue(ConstraintValue cValue)
    {
        cValue.Constraint = this;
        _values.Add(cValue);
    }
```

Back to the original question, I upgraded from Nhibernate 2.2 directly to NH 3.3.3.4001 and started to get the error "Invalid index n for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=n". I debugged with the NH source code, finding that the AbstractEntityPersister Dehydrate method goes through properties and set them on the sql command @p0, @p1, etc... and then it adds the Id as the last parameter. I'm using hilo id generation, so the id is known in advance.

Initially, I didn't have **inverse=true** on the parent side. 
Dehydrate was trying to set the sql command:

```
INSERT INTO [ConstraintValue] (ParameterId, Value, ConstraintId, OrderId, Id) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)
```

but somehow @p0 and @p3 were set to the same hilo Id, I was expected @p3 to be the "order" of the list (a number like 0, 1 or 2) and then it would try to set the actual Id of the object, as index=5, and I get the exception.

Then, I finally realised I missed **inverse=true**, and once corrected, I got this sql command in Dehydrate:

```
INSERT INTO [ConstraintValue] (ConstraintId, ParameterId, Value, Id) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3)
```

And this time, there was only 3 properties in the property array (@p0, @p1 and @p2), the "OrderId" is not even mentioned anywhere at this stage. These 3 properties are set in the for loop in Dehydrate, and then after that @p3 is set to the Id of the object by IdentifierType.NullSafeSet just after the for loop.

**To summarise, I got this exception not because I mapped the same column or property twice, but because I had a parent/child relationship without inverse=true on the parent.**